# Z-test for comparing two estimator values?

Tags: z-test

My supervisor asked me to compare values of Pohar Perme estimator of net survival in two regions of the country using Z-test. Am I right that we cannot use Z-test for comparing these estimator values? Pohar Perme estimator of net survival is defined in the paper available here (page 7 in PDF file or 191 acc. to page count): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254913594_Estimating_and_Modelling_Relative_Survival/download

I argue that Z-test can be used only for comparing means and fractions. Pohar Perme estimator of net survival is, actually, a weighted fraction. Am I right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not going to read the publication but if you're saying that the parameter in question is a weighted fraction then why wouldn't the Z test be applicable?

Comment: Thank you, Digo, for your suggestion. Actually there is no need to read the publication. Enough is to see the formular of the estimator on page 7 acc. do PDF page count.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.